# How can I make API requests between 2 internal APIs in one Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created an API .NET CORE project and it runs fine as my startup project, and has assigned 5001 as the port e.g. one of the calls is:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/Values/TESTME
```

I added a site cors policy in startup like so:

```
  services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SiteCors", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        });
```

Now I added another project (which runs on a different local host port) and set it as the startup project - it tries to do a WebRequest:

```
    string url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Values/TESTME";
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
```

which is rejected because `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I think adding a Firewall rule may be in order but 1) how exactly do I add a firewall rule for this? and 2) would this even work? Would I need both projects to be "running" in VS at the same time?

Comment: Is this for fun or do you really need this for something?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'd REALLY like to get this working - I'm trying to build a front-end with Razor pages that calls an API - they wouldn't necessarily have to be in the same project but I figured for testing it'd just be easier at this point. I don't really have time to learn the .JS frameworks for this so yeah, I kinda need it :/

Comment: Open up the ports on the firewall

Comment: And yes you need both running in separate instances unless you got 1 of them running in IIS or alt.

Comment: Actually just running them in separate instances of Visual Studio seems to work fine, didn't need to add any firewall rules (had to make sure the ports were different of course). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run both in *separate instances* on *separate ports* & it should be fine (if you haven't explicitly blocked anything in your firewall).

You could also run one API in IIS Server or self-hosted & the other running in Visual Studio.

Comment: If they're both on separate instances it means I can debug both at the same time! (if necessary) so I went for this option.